# Can I create the Input method picker fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am using below code to, open the picker to change the input method,my requirement is to  create it on full screen or customize it..

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.showInputMethodPicker();
```

it opens a dialog box..

desired output :

[image]

I didn't find any example for the same?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you require is the list of all the enabled IME's on the phone and a way to switch to one selected, fullscreen/dialog/whatever can be your UI implementation and it won't matter.

To get the list of the the enabled IME's try this :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
```

Once you have the list of input-methods, you can display them by name in anykind of dialog box and then switch to the selected one using the `void switchInputMethod (String id)` function available in `InputMethodService` class. The `id` for a particular ime can be extracted from the `InputMethodInfo` object that you retrieved earlier.